# How to set up Fastify correctly so that SvelteKit works fine?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, fastify

POST requests are not getting through and many other things are not working as expected.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example config:

```js
import { handler } from "./handler.js"; //file from adapter-node
import fastify from "fastify";
import rate_limit from "@fastify/rate-limit";
import helmet from "@fastify/helmet";

//todo
import file_upload from "fastify-file-upload";
import metrics from "@immobiliarelabs/fastify-metrics";
import websocket from "@fastify/websocket";
import msgpack from "fastify-msgpack";

(async () => {
    try {
        //fastify
        const app = fastify({
            connectionTimeout: 0,
            keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
            maxRequestsPerSocket: 0,
            requestTimeout: 0,
            ignoreTrailingSlash: true,
            bodyLimit: 1024 * 1024 * 10,
            disableRequestLogging: false,
        });

        //necessary!!!
        app.removeAllContentTypeParsers();
        app.addContentTypeParser("*", (req, payload, done) => done(null, null));

        //rate limit
        await app.register(rate_limit, {
            cache: 10000,
            allowList: ["127.0.0.1", "localhost"],
            keyGenerator: (req) => req.headers["x-real-ip"] || req.headers["x-client-ip"] || req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] || req.ip,
        });
        await app.register(helmet, { contentSecurityPolicy: false, crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false, });

        //other path
        app.get("/check", async (req, res) => {
            return "ok";
        });

        //rate limit
        app.get("/429", {
            config: {
                rateLimit: {
                    max: async (req, key) => {
                        return 1000;
                    },
                    timeWindow: 1000 * 60,
                }
            },
        }, (req, res) => handler(req.raw, res.raw, () => { }));

        app.all("/*", {
            config: {
                rateLimit: {
                    max: async (req, key) => {
                        if (req.url.startsWith("/api/")) {
                            return 500;
                        } else {
                            return 1000;
                        }
                    },
                    timeWindow: 1000 * 60,
                }
            },
            errorHandler: (error, req, res) => {
                if (error.message.startsWith("Rate limit exceeded")) {
                    res.code(302).redirect("/429");
                } else {
                    throw error;
                }
            }
        }, (req, res) => handler(req.raw, res.raw, () => { }));

        await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        process.exit(-1);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Why do you need `app.addContentTypeParser("*", (req, payload, done) => done(null, null));`? It sounds like it would remove all request bodies, so things you'd expect to be there wouldn't.

Comment: @mrkishi Fastify automatically parses the body when requested if it is text or json. And kit is currently parsing the body from request raw with .on, respectively, by this time the body has already been read and the request begins to wait indefinitely.

Comment: How are trying to connect the two? Is there a fastify adapter for SvelteKit?